# Random password generation

Tags: java

I have written a code for random password generation.There are a string from where i have to make the password.so i try to categorize the string according to uppercase array , lower case array and digit array. but here comes a problem when..

```
         for(int k=0;k<Length;k++){
        if(asc[k]>=65 && asc[k]<=90){
            UpperCase[k]=(char)asc[k];
        }
        else if(asc[k]>=48 && asc[k]<=57){
            Digit[k]=(char)asc[k];
        }
        else {
            Mixed[k]=(char)asc[k];
        }
    }
```

is executed it counts some space which i don't want.coding looks like ugly sry for my poor coding.i know there is a lot more way to solve it but i want to go through this.here is my code. here is my code

```
import java.util.Random;

   public class Randompassgeneration
   {

final int MAX_LENGTH = 20;
final int MIN_LENGTH = 3;

char[] password=new char[25];
int [] asc=new int[18];
char[] UpperCase=new char[25];
char[] Digit=new char[25];
char[] Mixed=new char[25];
public void generate(String allowedCharacters)
{
    int Length=allowedCharacters.length();


    for (int i=0;i<Length;i++)
    {
        asc[i]=(int)allowedCharacters.charAt(i);

    }
    for (int k=0;k<Length;k++)
    {
        if (asc[k]>=65 && asc[k]<=90)
        {
            UpperCase[k]=(char)asc[k];
        }
        else if (asc[k]>=48 && asc[k]<=57)
        {
            Digit[k]=(char)asc[k];
        }
        else
        {
            Mixed[k]=(char)asc[k];
        }
    }

    String rp=null;
    StringBuilder Strbld=new StringBuilder();
    Random rnd=new Random();
    int ranStrLen=rnd.nextInt(MAX_LENGTH - MIN_LENGTH + 1) + MIN_LENGTH;
    Strbld.append(UpperCase[rnd.nextInt(UpperCase.length)]);
    Strbld.append(Digit[rnd.nextInt(Digit.length)]);

    for (int m=0; m<ranStrLen-2; m++)
    {
        Strbld.append(Mixed[rnd.nextInt(Mixed.length)]);

    }

    System.out.print(ranStrLen +"->"+ Strbld.toString());


}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String allowedCharacters = "weakPasSWorD1234$*";
    Randompassgeneration t=new Randompassgeneration();
    t.generate(allowedCharacters);
}
}
```

Any kind of suggestion?

Comment: I have serious trouble to understand what you are asking here. What do you mean by `it counts some space`? Counts spaces?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you want to do exactly? What is `allowedCharacters` for?

Comment: seems like hard working but not smart working , try to reduce the complexity of the code

Comment: i just want to know what is the easiest way to break each and every char of a string into their category ....suppose there is a string 
"ASDFasdf1234" now i want three array 
uppercase[] lowercase[] and digit[] 
the uppercase array will contain ASDF
lowercase array will contain asdf....

Comment: generating random number from allowedcharacter string @mOskito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"is executed it counts some space which i don't want"*

**The white space is beacuse of your `For loop`**

You were using the variable `k` for all the arrays,which resulted into the incremented value of `k` each time.So,this was making "gaps" between your arrays.

Change it to:

```
int point1=0,point2=0,point3=0;
for (int k=0;k<Length;k++)
{
    if (asc[k]>=65 && asc[k]<=90)
    {
        UpperCase[point1]=(char)asc[k];point1++;
        continue;
    }
    else if (asc[k]>=48 && asc[k]<=57)
    {
        Digit[point2]=(char)asc[k];point2++;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        Mixed[point3]=(char)asc[k];point3++;
    }

}
System.out.println(UpperCase);
System.out.println(Digit);
System.out.println(Mixed);
```

OutPut:

```
PSWD
1234
weakasor$*
```

Answer (score 2):

I would generate the minimum number of characters, digits and symbols. Fill the other characters randomly and shuffle the result.  This way it will comply with your minimum requirements with a minimum of effort.

```
public static String passwordGenerator() {
    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    // min number of digits
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) chars.add((char) ('0' + rand.nextInt(10)));
    // min number of lower case
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) chars.add((char) ('a' + rand.nextInt(26)));
    // min number of upper case
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) chars.add((char) ('A' + rand.nextInt(26)));
    // min number of symbols
    String symbols = "!\"$%^&*()_+{}:@~<>?,./;'#][=-\\|'";
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) chars.add(symbols.charAt(rand.nextInt(symbols.length())));
    // fill in the rest
    while (chars.size() < 8) chars.add((char) ('!' + rand.nextInt(93)));
    // appear in a random order
    Collections.shuffle(chars);
    // turn into a String
    char[] arr = new char[chars.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++) arr[i] = chars.get(i);
    return new String(arr);
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        System.out.println(passwordGenerator());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok if not mistaken you want to parse the password generated and want put them in separate array. Here is the snippet for uppercase.

```
ArrayList<Character> uppercase = new ArrayList<Character>();

char pass[] = password.toCharArray();
for(char c: pass){
   if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
         uppercase.add(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random string, you could do:

```
public String getRandomString(){
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

If you want to make it consistent with some source String, you could do:

```
public String getConsistentHash(String source){
    return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(source.getBytes()).toString();
}
```

This latter method will return the same String for the same source String.

If there is a only a limited set of characters you want to use, you could just replace the unwanted chars. Suppose you have have created "randomString" as above, you create "randomString1" with:

```
randomString1 = UUID.fromString(randomString);
```

Now replace the unwanted chars in "randomString" with the chars in "randomString1". You could repeat this if necessary.

If you do not care for a minimum size/spread, you could just remove the chars.

Good luck.